# Inconsistent assembly loading behavior in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I was debugging why a powershell script started failing and it looked like it was using Hashset without referencing the System.Core assembly, so the fix is to end up with something like this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Core
$hash = new-object 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]'
```

What I can't figure out is how it was working before, and still runs just fine on some machines, without the add-type line. What am I missing here?

Comment: Check $profile to see if it's loading that assembly on those machines?

Comment: Different PowerShell versions?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I double checked, there is no profile file on either machine.

Comment: @ojk same powershell version on both machines.

Comment: My guess is that assembly was previously loaded by another application on your other machine. Try [appdomain]::currentdomain.GetAssemblies() on both and see if System.Core is loaded.

Comment: FWIW, on my machine, `System.Core` is always loaded, even if I start PowerShell with `-NoProfile -version <anything>` (the installed version is 3.0).

Comment: What was the error you were getting, when it was failing without the `System.Core` `Add-Type` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To continue from David's thought, and because code in comments is horrid, you should check to see if the assembly is loaded. A small blog about checking assemblies is [here](https://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2007/09/30/assemblies-loaded-in-powershell/)

```
If (!(([appdomain]::currentdomain.GetAssemblies()).FullName -match "System\.Core")){
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Core
}
$hash = new-object 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]'
```

I have this assembly loaded by default. Curious what the affected systems have. What is the Dot.Net framework versions on affected machines? I had some of my 3.5 code stop working after Windows updates and need to reinstall framework.

Comment from **Jeroen Mostert**

> If you want to be *really* precise about it, you should verify you've
>   got .NET's very own `System.Core`, not any old impostor, and then
>   there is no need to check that's already happened. `Add-Type
>   -AssemblyName "System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"`

Comment: Well if you want to be *really precise* about it, you should verify you've got .NET's very own `System.Core`, not any old impostor, and then there is no need to check that's already happened. `Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"` on its own is enough (version policies will take care of loading a later version if necessary).

Comment: @JeroenMostert good plan. Mine looks like this `System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089` not sure which one the op needs. Thanks. I'm still not sure if I should just delete this or not.

Comment: Because `HashSet` exists in 3.5, I'd go with that to maximize the chance of the script running. Unless you specifically need .NET 4.0, of course, but then that won't be because of `HashSet`.

Comment: The issue is going to be that if the default environment already has `System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, ...` loaded -- and that assembly should load automatically if you have PowerShell 4.0, AFAIK -- then `Add-Type` will fail:  ["The type name and namespace must be unique within a session. You cannot unload a type or change it. If you need to change the code for a type, you must change the name or start a new Windows PowerShell session. Otherwise, the command fails."](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/5cf4d98b-ff0a-4ead-aa3a-c842d892ab9b(v=wps.630).aspx) (See `-Name` parameter)

Comment: @BaconBits: except that's not true. I tried it on my own system, and `Add-Type` does not fail at all when attempting to load version 3.5 of `System.Core` is version 4.0 is already loaded (Powershell 3.0). This makes sense, since asking for 3.5 on .NET 4.0 will just get you 4.0, courtesy of versioning policy.